# WSO2 API data persistency issue

Tags: docker, api, wso2-api-manager, wso2

I am currently using WSO2 with Docker. I have published some APIs on the store but if Docker reboots all loose all my APIs.

Therefore, I have followed this tutorial https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/reference/common-runtime-and-configuration-artifacts/#common-runtime-and-configuration-artifacts to create a folder that I mount into the wso2-artifact-volume.

But when launching the Publisher it says that no APIs found.

If I look at the logs, it seems that they have been imported.

```
[2021-03-23 17:52:56,735]  INFO - API {api:admin--PmrPUBLIC:v1.0.0.0} Initializing API: admin--PmrPUBLIC:v1.0.0.0

[2021-03-23 17:52:56,735]  INFO - API {api:admin--DeletePmr:v1.0.0} Initializing API: admin--DeletePmr:v1.0.0

[2021-03-23 17:52:56,735]  INFO - API {api:admin--EditPMR:v1.0.0} Initializing API: admin--EditPMR:v1.0.0

[2021-03-23 17:52:56,736]  INFO - API {api:_WSO2AMLoginContextAPI_} Initializing API: _WSO2AMLoginContextAPI_

[2021-03-23 17:52:56,736]  INFO - API {api:_WSO2AMAuthorizeAPI_} Initializing API: _WSO2AMAuthorizeAPI_

[2021-03-23 17:52:56,736]  INFO - API {api:_WSO2AMUserInfoAPI_} Initializing API: _WSO2AMUserInfoAPI_

[2021-03-23 17:52:56,736]  INFO - API {api:_OpenService_} Initializing API: _OpenService_

[2021-03-23 17:52:56,736]  INFO - API {api:_WSO2AMRevokeAPI_} Initializing API: _WSO2AMRevokeAPI_

[2021-03-23 17:52:56,740]  INFO - API {api:_WSO2AMTokenAPI_} Initializing API: _WSO2AMTokenAPI_

[2021-03-23 17:52:56,741]  INFO - API {api:_WSO2OIDCAPI_} Initializing API: _WSO2OIDCAPI_

[2021-03-23 17:52:56,741]  INFO - ServerManager Server ready for processing...
```

If I go check on the WSO2 carbon under List>APIs it says:

```
There are no APIs added.
```

What is strange is that I have also used some configuration artifacts such as hostname change and this works fine as far as the server is concerned.

To make sure that there is no read/write access issue with those files, I have used the following commands on the mounted volume:

```
chown -R ${USER}:${USER} ./<my_folder>
chmod -R 777 ./<my_folder>
```

I am a bit lost and do not know what to do now.

Could you please help me out?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you see APIs in the publisher? What happens when you create a new API in the publisher?

Comment: No there are no APIs in the Publisher and if I create one I can see it.

Comment: Looks like an indexing issue. Can u remove solr and h2 db mount and restart the container?

Comment: When doing so I can see in the console logs that each of my APIs "was added to the Synapse configuration successfully" but there is still nothing in the Publisher for whatever reason.

Comment: You can remove h2 and solr mounts. Then use the following config in the deployment.toml and start the server for indexing.

[indexing]
re_indexing = 1

Answer (score 0):

I did manage to persist my APIs data by creating a folder named "data-mysql" (it is important to add read-write access on that folder) then I simply mount that folder with the MySQL container with the following command (./data-mysql:/var/lib/mysql). The MySQL container is used to store data related to users, apis, etc. Therefore it is a good option to bind the databases with a folder in the host machine.